# RabbitMQ RPC load balancing

Tags: rabbitmq, load-balancing, rpc, request-response

Do RabbitMQ RPC (request-response) communication model support load balancing?

I have seen many examples using RPC with RabbitMQ but none of them mentioned load balancing support.

It will be great if a client will be able to send a request to a request queue (or exchange), and one of the servers will take the request, handle it and return a response to the client. Via a dedicated return queue or direct reply-to technique.

Does RabbitMQ support something like this?

Answer (score 1):

That is easily achievable by having a consumer in the request queue for each server.

Each server should have its `QoS` configured and avoid acknowledging the messages until they have been processed, that way the broker would only send messages to the servers that are ready.

Comment: Thanks. If both servers will be ready, the message will be sent to both? Both will process and only one will ack? Or  the message broker will only send each message to one of the servers? Using "direct reply-to" will still be possible?

Comment: @Marco The messages in the queue are delivered only once, if both consumers are ready, only one of them will get the message (unless the message is nacked or the connection to the consumer is lost, in that case it's redelivered). RPC is built on top of RabbitMQ capabilities, RabbitMQ itself does not know about the reply-to in any case, so yes, using that is still possible